# xpath/python search then grab child nodes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I am working on a scraper using python and selenium and I have an issue traversing xpath.  I feel like this should be simple, but I'm obviously missing something.

I am able to navigate the site I am browsing fine, but I need to grab some SPAN text based on an XPATH search.

I am able to click the appropriate radio button(in this case the 1st one)

```
(driver.find_elements_by_name("start-date"))[0].click()
```

But I also need to capture the text next to the radio button which is captures in the span tags.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="start-date" value="1" data-start-date="/Date(1507854300000)/" data-end-date="/Date(1508200200000)/" group="15" type-id="8">
        <span class="start-date">
            10/12/2017<br>Summary text
        </span>
</label>
```

In the above example, I'm looking to capture "10/12/2017" and "Summary text" into 2 string variables based on the find_elements_by_name search I used to find the radio button.

I then have a second, similar, collection issue, where I need to capture the span tags after searching by class name.  This finds the appropriate parent node on the page:

```
(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class=\"MyClass\"]"))
```

Based on the node returned by that search, I want to grab "Text 1" and "Text 2" from the span tags below it.

```
<div class="MyClass">
    <span>
        <span>Text 1</span>
    </span>
        <span class="bullet">
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>Text 2</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I am new to xpath, but from what I can gather, the span nodes I am looking for should be children of the nodes I found with my searches, and I should be able to traverse down the hierarchy somehow to get the values, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Good Question, because both are in same span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very simple, all `WebElement` objects have the same `find_element_by_*` methods that the `WebDriver` object has, with the main difference that the element methods change the context to that element, meaning that it will only have children of the selected element.

With that in mind you should be able to do:

```
my_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('MyClass')
my_spans = my_element.find_elements_by_css_selector('span>span')
```

What happens here is that we grab the first element with class `MyClass`, then from the context of that element we search for elements that are span AND children of a span

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the following x-path.

```
//div[@class='MyClass']/span[1]/span  ---- To get Text 1
//div[@class='MyClass']/span[3]/span  -----To get Text 2
```

or

```
(//div[@class='MyClass']/span/span)[1] ---- To get Text 1
(//div[@class='MyClass']/span/span)[2] ---- To get Text 2
```